# iptables - sendmail send out only

Tags: linux, iptables, sendmail

I have had a look around and tried a number of things.

If I want a (centos) server to only be able to send emails (notifications to me) but have no other internet access in or out then what are the iptables.

I have tried this but does not work, only sends email when iptables is stopped.

```
   iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m tcp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT
```

Any help/knowledge?

Sendmail log shows:  stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1] when iptables active

Update:
The following rules appear to work:

```
   iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT
```

Comment: I just read something about allowing DNS - added port 53 in and out rules and still not working.

Comment: DNS needs both UDP and TCP enabled

Comment: Which mta are you using? What does it log when it fails?

Comment: @CHinSU better update your question. Also, your rules for incoming DNS traffic is incorrect - you are specifying dport as 53, you need to use state to allow incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendmail-8.12+ passes "command line emails" via 127.0.0.1:25. It does it to avoid being installed as set root uid.

You can make sendmail accept incoming SMTP connection only on 127.0.0.1 (loopback interfaces). It should block incoming external SMTP connections.
Add the following line to sendail.mc and recopile it into sendmail.cf [[1]](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/sendmail-on-127-0-0-1-only-203386/):

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Addr=127.0.0.1,Port=smtp,Name=MTA')
```

You may also try the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -d 127.0.0.1 -i lo -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state NEW -j REJECT 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -j REJECT
```